# Need help with Image Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, rollover

```
<a href="#" 
    onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
    onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','Images/menuButtons/home_out.png',1)" 
    onclick="alert("Hello")" ><img onclick="alert("Hello")" 
    src="Images/menuButtons/home_on.png" 
    alt="Home" name="Home" width="164" height="64" border="0" id="Home" />
</a><br/>
```

I'm trying to create a navigation menubar with rollover images. Rollover Image part was created by Dreamweaver hence all those `MM_functions`. But `onclick`, I want to change the content of main frame, not just open a hyperlink.

So I tried `onclick="JS_funtion()"` aswell as `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUP`. Nothing seemed to work. It's not even calling the functions as the example shows, I tried to call `alert()` and still not working. I'm new to HTML/Javascript.

What am I doing wrong?

My site is [www.sitebloviate.com](http://www.sitebloviate.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arjan is right, you can't use double quotes inside a double-quoted attribute.

Other things:

- you don't need `onclick` in your image, the anchor tag will do,
- setting `href="#"` is generally bad practice.  It's better to make it a real link so that if the user right-clicks and chooses "open in new tab" it takes them somewhere meaningful.

To do the latter though, you'll need to cancel the event by returning false.

Example:

```
<a href="/path/to/real/page" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','Images/menuButtons/home_out.png',1)" onclick="alert('Hello'); return false;" >
<img src="Images/menuButtons/home_on.png" alt="Home" name="Home" width="164" height="64" border="0" id="Home" /></a><br/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you replace `onclick="alert("Hello")"` with `onclick="alert('Hello')"` (note the different quotes between ( and ) ) it will work.

Comment: you guys are just too quick! +1

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is your `onclick="alert("Hello")"` should be `onclick="alert('Hello')"` with single quotes to indicate a literal string.  It's probably choking there.